# Check if string contains slash or backslash in Bash?

Tags: regex, string, bash, backslash

I'm currently trying to get my bash script checking if a string containts a `"/"` or a `"\"` but somehow I can't get it working.

Here is what I got so far:

```sh
if [[ "$1" == *\/* ]]; then
   ...
elif if [[ "$1" == *\\* ]]; then
   ...
fi
```

Help is much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: `case "$string" in *\\*|*\/*) echo yes;; esac`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This checks if either `\` or `/` are in the variable `$string`.

```
if [[ "$string" == *\/* ]] || [[ "$string" == *\\* ]]
then
  echo "yes"
fi
```

#### Test:

```
$ string="hello"
$ if [[ "$string" == *\/* ]] || [[ "$string" == *\\* ]]; then echo "yes"; fi
$
$ string="hel\lo"
$ if [[ "$string" == *\/* ]] || [[ "$string" == *\\* ]]; then echo "yes"; fi
yes
$ string="hel//lo"
$ if [[ "$string" == *\/* ]] || [[ "$string" == *\\* ]]; then echo "yes"; fi
yes
```

Comment: No need for the surrounding `*`s if you use `=~` instead of `==`.

Comment: You can also write `[[ "$string" == *\/* || "$string" == *\\* ]]`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the comments below @fedorqui answer, here is a simpler syntax:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

string=$1
if [[ "$string" =~ '/' || "$string" =~ '\' ]]
then
  echo "yes"
fi
```