# How do I find out if a parameter contains a "/" and if it does create the directory before it and the file after it

Tags: linux, bash, grep, delimiter

I am trying to create a script that takes a parameter with a / in the between the directory and file. I then want to create the directory and create the file inside that directory. I don't really have a huge idea of what I am doing so I don't have any code other than the basic skeleton  for a bash if statement.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 ?? "/" ]; then
   do
fi
```

If for example the parameter of Website/Google is passed a directory called Website should be created with a file called Google inside it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a string contains a substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/229551/608639), [Check if string containts slash or backslash in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18148883/608639), [How to check the first character in a string in Bash or UNIX shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18488270/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ "$1" = */* ]];
  dir=${1#/*}
  file=${1%%*/}
fi
```

in `bash`, or more generally for a POSIX-compatible shell,

```
case $1 in
  */*) dir=${1#/*}; file=${1%%*/} ;;
esac
```